# Java - linux pipeline

Tags: java, linux, pipeline

I need to implement a pipeline such that I can provide inpu/output to a java run, basically I want to avoid reading and writing from disk. I have never implemented one, I tried some thing that do not work. Here you can see conceptually what I want to do. This is the shell script. tmp/result should work as input/output. I have searched around but I could not come up with the solution.

thanks in advance

Altober

```
#!/bin/bash

fName=$1
max=$2
finished=0
last=0

result=""
tmp=""

while [ $finished -lt $max ] 
do

last=$((finished + 1000))
echo $last

java  -cp bin:"lib/*" Evaluation.Evaluation $fName $finished $last < result > tmp

finished=$((finished + 1000))
result=$tmp

echo $finished
done
```

Comment: Implementing a pipeline stage involves nothing more than reading from stdin, and writing to stdout.

Comment: Yes thanks, I understand, but is this the correct way to implement it? Is the Java line correct? It does not work.

Comment: What does "it does not work" mean?  If your Java process is correctly reading from stdin and writing to stdout, then it should work.

Comment: I am getting result: No such file or directory. It seems that it is still trying to read from disk

Comment: Well, is there a file called `result`?

Comment: no but this is the point, I want the information to be stored in the variable result which I defined in my shell script. Is this possible?

Comment: Of course, but you first of all need to actually *use* the variable, i.e. `$result` rather than `result`, and you also need to initialise it with an actual filename, rather than just an empty string.

Comment: Ok, now it works but my concern is. Will the file be written in each iteration? Why should I create an unnecessary file? Can I just create a variable in the script which remains in memory for the entire run? thanks again for your help.

Comment: result=\`java  -cp bin:"lib/*" Evaluation.Evaluation $fName $finished $last $result\`

Comment: thanks tigran but I cannot follow, result should be the output of the program

Comment: yes, result will contain the output of the program. This is so called "command substitution". Check here http://bashshell.net/shell-scripts/using-command-substitution-in-a-bash-shell-script/